# Liquid's Ceil/Floor Filters on a Variable Not Working as Expected

Tags: shopify, shopify-liquid

I'm facing a weird issue that I can't get past.

Context: I have some metaobjects setup for product reviews and product metafields which reference reviews corresponding to that product. I'm trying to display the reviews on the front-end using a custom liquid section. I am able to access the data but am facing a very weird issue when working with the rating data. The rating field is set up using a `rating` type metafield, so its value if fetched using something like `{{ review.rating.value }}`.

I'm looping over all the reviews for a product and displaying the reviews' data, like so:

```
{% for review in product.metafields.something_reviews.reviews.value %}
    <article class="review-wrapper">
        <div class="review-rating">
            {% assign rating = review.rating.value %}
            {% assign ratingCeil = rating|ceil  %}
            {% for star in (1..ratingCeil) %}
                <span class="rating-star"></span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <p class="review-text">
            {{ review.review }}
        </p>
        <p class="author-text">
            {{ review.author  }}
        </p>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm facing a problem with the following section of code:

```
{% assign rating = review.rating.value %}
{% assign ratingCeil = rating|ceil  %}
{% for star in (1..ratingCeil) %}
    <span class="rating-star"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

Let's assume that the rating for a review is `4.2` (I've kept the field user-editable so that value could be any decimal even though it doesn't make sense for a single review). In this case, the value of `review.rating.value|ceil` should be `5`. However, for me, it is showing up as `0`. If I directly output `{{ 4.2|ceil }}` or even `{{ "4.2"|ceil }}` to test, it gives the correct answer but not when I pass it into a variable like above.

I just cannot understand what is going on here. It's making me lose my mind a little.  Any help on this front will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

PS: The same thing is happening if I use the `floor` filter.

Comment: Are you sure `review.rating.value` is holding the value `4.2`? What happens if you use `{{ review.rating.value }}`?

Comment: You need to convert it to integer, use something like `{% assign ratingCeil = rating | plus: 0 |ceil  %}`

Comment: @Onkar no `ceil` and `floor` do that conversation internally.

Comment: @derpirscher can you please explain more, about how the same is handle internally?

Comment: @Onkar  You can do `{% assign val="4.2" %} {{ val | ceil }}` and it will output 5 as expected, even though val is a string...

Comment: But if you pass an empy variable into `ceil` it will output 0. Like `{% assign val="" %} {{ val | ceil }}`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I don't have much expertise with liquid, so I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Onkar then maybe you should familiarize yourself with it before giving wrong advise

Answer (score -1):

Possibly an issue with the field value not considered as an integer but a string.

You might try this:

```
{% assign rating = review.rating.value | plus:0 %}
```

Comment: Nope. Liquid does those kind of checks/conversions internally and it's perfectly fine to do something like `{% assign val="4.2" %} {{ val | ceil }}`